# How to get a file or a piece of code from gerrit code review instead of getting the entire project when cloning it?

Tags: git, repository, clone, gerrit

When I am trying to clone a project from the gerrit code review I am getting the entire project.  My question is how to get a file or a piece of code from gerrit code review instead of getting the entire project ?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

1. Go to Gerrit > Projects > List > Filter and find the project
2. Click on the "Repository Browser" link on the right side
3. Use the browser features (specific for your Gerrit server) to download what you want